# Symfony Session on module

Tags: session, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Generally when I try to search for the solution they direct me to security.yml in the config folder. But whenever I change it to my module name lets says "user"

```
user:
    is_secure: true
```

it doesn't work while....

```
all:
    is_secure: true
```

locked up all the page so what should I do to handling on specific modules or files if possible. Thanks for the valuable time and comment.

Edit:

My path

```
<!-- apps/frontend/modules/user -->
```

originally under user folder doesn't have config folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to secure an specific module you have to define it in **its** config folder at **security.yml** file (like you said but in the desire module). For example, if I have a *clients* module with *index*, *new*, *create*, etc actions and want to secure the *new* and *create* actions, you have to add to the

```
<!-- /app_name/modules/clients/config/security.yml -->
new:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: [...] //if you defined credentials

create:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: [...] //if you defined credentials
```

If you want to secure all clients module just set

```
<!-- /app_name/modules/clients/config/security.yml -->
all:
  is_secure: true
```

Comment: ohh, my folder is something like this <!-- /app_name/frontend/modules/user --> so necessary to go into user modules and create another folder namely config/security.yml ?

Comment: as in default my modules/user doesn't have config folder > <

Comment: yes, you have to create the config/security.yml into, in your case, user module.

Comment: hmmm no luck yet after make the folder... do I have to tell symfony that I have made a new folder config with security.yml inside ?

Comment: Did you clear cache? Check http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security that has the official documentation

Comment: ahhh okay ady, didn't know indexSuccess was actually index in yml :D thanks